# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns wrong date even when TimeZone details supplied with string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE','dd MMM YYYY z"];

NSString *string = @"Thursday,11 Jun 2015 +0530";

NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];
```

Now when I NSLog..

```
NSLog(@"%@",[tempDate description]);
```

2014-12-24 18:30:00 +0000

```
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:tempDate]);
```

Thursday,25 Dec 2014 IST

Why is it not showing 'Thursday,11 Jun 2015 IST' instead 'Thursday,25 Dec 2014 IST' ?

Comment: What is  x here `"EEEE','dd MMM YYYY x"`? You can use NSLocal to set timezone

Answer (score 2):

```
if you change to 'yyyy' will show you result like.
```

> Thursday,11 Jun 2015 +0530

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormattor = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormattor setDateFormat:@"EEEE','dd MMM yyyy zzzz"];
 NSTimeZone *_timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"IST"];
[dateFormattor setTimeZone:_timezone];
NSString *string = @"Thursday,11 Jun 2015 +0530";
NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormattor dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"tempDate is :%@",tempDate);
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormattor stringFromDate:tempDate]);
```

> Thursday,11 Jun 2015 India Standard Time

change in line at 'z' char you get different results.

```
[dateFormattor setDateFormat:@"EEEE','dd MMM yyyy zzzz"];
```

1. z = GMT+0530 IST
2. zz = GMT+0530 IST
3. zzz = GMT+0530 IST
4. zzzz = India Standard Time IST
5. zzzzz = India Standard Time IST

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I changed 'YYYY' to 'yyyy' and it worked. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Also see QA1480. There's a low probability of issues but really you should set the locaale if you definitely need to hit your date format string. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *outDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
outDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
outDateFormatter.dateFormat = (your date formate)
```

Try using this